# Does d3js data binding clone the data being bound or store a reference to it?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I use d3 to generate a bunch of DOM elements using a data set, I maintain a reference to the data object.

At a later point in time if I modify the data object - add/remove elements change properties etc. - Could I then reevaluate attributes on the DOM elements and expect it to reflect the modifications made to the data object?

e.g.

```
existingElements.attr('x', function(d) { return d.size; });
```

Comment: Not difficult to test by yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/KuhZ9/.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can expect them to update.

With out more code it is hard to guess but you can use something like this:

```
var els = d3.select("body").selectAll("div");//Cache elements
els.style('background','blue')//Change background to blue;
els.style('background','red')//Change background to red;
els.style("width", function(d) {
        return d *1/3 + "px"; //Divide elements width by 3
    });
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PPcfN/7/)